# SVNSERVE - Do all repositories have to be in same parent folder?

Tags: svn, repository-design, svnserve

Here is my situation:

I have inherited an SVN server (using svnserve only on Win 2008 R2) with a small hard disk and a repository without a specified name.  It's path is `C:\svn\repos`.  I would rather not change anything about it if possible, and the disk is fine for that project.

Another group wants a new repository created on this server.  I am getting a new hard disk added.
Can I just go to D:, create a folder called `D:\svn\repos\Project2`, `cd\svn\repos\Project2`, and then use the `svnadmin create` command to create their new repository?

We use TortoiseSVN as a client if that matters...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends.

If you're running svnserve with the `-r` parameter, then svnserve will only serve repositories which are immediate child directories of the directory specified by that parameter.

If you do not use the `-r` parameter, then you can place the repositories anywhere, as you have to specify the full path to the repository on the server.

See [the manual](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn-book.html#svn.serverconfig.svnserve) for documentation of the various ways svnserve can be invoked.

Comment: Thanks! Can I specify more than one path for svnserve, or do I run more than one instance of svnserve?  There are no examples of what I'm trying to accomplish, that's why I'm asking here.

Comment: If you need 2 paths which do not share a common immediate parent, then you need two instances of svnserve. Or one instance of svnserve and in the URL specify the full path on the server for the repository (this is not a desirable situation). Really, you're best off consolidating all repositories into a single common parent. That'll be a brief pain for people who currently have working copies pointing to it, but in the end it'll be worth it.

Comment: can you use the mounted devices?

Answer (score 0):

Use can use the one root path for repos for svnserve instance. But you can try to use the `symlink` virtual paths from svn repo root, linked to several paths

Try `MKLINK`

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753194%28WS.10%29.aspx